# Which tags to use for good SEO on the page

Tags: seo, web-development, search-engines

I have a event page, where it has the following items.

1. Event Name
2. Venue Name(s) {some cases go upto 5 or more venues}
3. Event Info {Genre(s),Language,type(s)}
4. Date(s) on which the event is.
5. Event Description.

Since, the Event name is unique, and present in the title, I am assigning `<H1>` to it.

However, venue names are multiple, plus the same venue may be repeated across the page, along with dates.

(Each)Event Info, is used a single time on the page
Dates, are descriped in a styled manner using multiple spans, however, I am going to use a `title` on them.

Event description is in `<p>` tag.

So My question is which heading tags to use for a good symentic description and SEO.
Also the `title` on the dates, which format should I keep the date in? (dd/mm/yyyy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [microdata](http://schema.org/) to semantically mark up your content, so that, for example, Google can generate [rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506) from it.  Here's an example from the [Event schema documentation](http://schema.org/Event):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <a itemprop="url" href="nba-miami-philidelphia-game3.html">
  NBA Eastern Conference First Round Playoff Tickets:
  <span itemprop="name"> Miami Heat at Philadelphia 76ers - Game 3 (Home Game 1) </span>
  </a>

  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-04-21T20:00">
    Thu, 04/21/16
    8:00 p.m.

  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <a itemprop="url" href="wells-fargo-center.html">
    Wells Fargo Center
    </a>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Philadelphia</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">PA</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
    Priced from: <span itemprop="lowPrice">$35</span>
    <span itemprop="offerCount">1938</span> tickets left
  </div>
</div>
```

And yes, using `<h1>` for the event name seems perfectly fine, if that's what the page is about.  That will work fine together with microdata, e.g.:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Event Name</h1>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful, going through it.
However, is it ok to have multiple `<h2>` tags?, say if the second most important thing in the page is the venue name? Or will search engines ignore the tags due to multiple usages?

Comment: Yeah, multiple `<h2>` tags are OK; one would typically use them for section headings.  In fact, there's no actual rule saying you can't have multiple `<h1>` tags too, although "one per page" is a good rule of thumb.  Just don't overuse them; search engines _will_ notice if you try something silly like putting _all_ your content in `<h1>` tags.